# JSONP & jQuery Chunking

Tags: jquery, cross-domain, jsonp

I am wanting to utilize JSONP for a project with x-domain scripting but little concerned with the 2048 character limit in IE.

Does JSONP support "chunking" automatically if character size exceeds 2048 ? If yes, does anyone have any examples they can share ?

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This limit applies only to request URIs. Your JSONP response does not suffer from such limitation. jQuery will simply insert a `script` tag inside the DOM pointing to the request URL which will return the JSONP encoded content which can be as big as you wish.

Comment: Ya but I think this doesn't answer the question. If one were to simulate a really long post with jsonp, is there anything that can do multiple url requests as chunks?